# Php delete from multiple tables

Tags: php

I have a basic backoffice setup with a few tables listing the database content with an option to delete the rows, based on the id. But for every product that I have, I need to have different PHP delete files, in this example, `"product_01"`, `"product_02"`, etc.

How can I pass a custom id in the query string (`href='delete_product_01.php?id=...`) so I can have a conditional statement in the delete php file, this way I would only need one delete.php file.

Thank you

*back.php.php*

```
echo "<td class='deleteMe'><a class='delete_back' href='delete_product_01.php?id=".$record['id']."'>x</a></td>";
```

*delete_product_01.php*

```
include('config_delete.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM product_01_table WHERE id='$id'");
    if ($query) {
        header('location:back.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Every product has its own table? That sounds like a DB design flaw, or am I reading this question wrong? You are open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: ***Please*** have a look here: http://www.bobby-tables.com.  This code is very unsafe.  What if I tried to go to `delete_product_01.php?id=' OR 1=1; -- `?

Comment: I don't get why people keep using mysql, at least use mysqli_* if you don't want to learn prepared statements yet. but nonetheless, I don't understand how the database is set up. Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the product id as second get parameter, like

```
delete_product.php?id=4&product_id=1
```

And in your **delete.php** you could manipulate your string in some way like

```
"delete from product_".$_GET["product_id"]."_table where id='$id'"
```

but you really should ***NOT*** do this!

Here are multiple reasons, why such code design is VERY dangerous and bad:

---

### SQL-Injection

One could easily exploit your get parameter to get evil sql code executed. Imagine someone calling

```
delete_product.php?id=4';DROP database;
```

By doing that, he would not only delete one product, he would delete everything.
Have a look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) for more information about that.

### mysql_* functions

`mysql_*` functions are long deprecated and should not be used. There are many reasons for this, have a look at [this SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

### Database design

Having a designated table for every single Product of yours is very bad database design. Imagine your company (or whatever instance is selling here) making a change in their product portfolio, removing or adding a product. You would need to make a huge amount of changes. If you consider revising your concept (You really should!) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377375/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-database-design) will provide you with a good starting point.