# MySQL LEFT JOIN or WHERE IN SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql, join

I need a piece of advice, building an app now and I need to run some queries on rather large tables, possibly at a very frequent rate, so I'm trying to get the best approach performance wise.

I have the following 2 tables:

Albums:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|     Field     |     Type     | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eventid       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| album         | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filename      | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| obstacle_time | time         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and keywords:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|    Field    |     Type     | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eventid     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| filename    | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bibnumbers  | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gender      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| top_style   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pants_style | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| other       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cap         | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tshirt      | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pants       | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Both table have a unique_index declared which is a constraint of the `eventid+filename` column.

Both table contains information about some images, but the albums table is available instantly (as soon as I have the images), while the keywords table usually becomes available several days later after a manual tagging of the images is completed

Now I will have people searching for all kind of things once the tagging is enabled, but since the results can be HUGE (up to 10.000 or more) I'm only showing them in small chunks so the browser doesn't get killed with trying to load a huge amount of images, because of this my server will be hit with loads of query requests (every time the visitor scrolls to the bottom of the page, an ajax query will return the next chunk of images).

Now my question is, which of the following queries is better performance wise:

```
SELECT `albums`.`filename`,`basket`.`id`,`albums`.`id`,`obstacle_time`
FROM `albums`
LEFT JOIN `basket`
    ON `basket`.`eventid` = `albums`.`eventid`
        AND `basket`.`fileid` = `albums`.`id`
        AND `basket`.`visitor_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN `keywords`
    ON `keywords`.`eventid` = `albums`.`eventid`
        AND `albums`.`filename` = `keywords`.`filename`
WHERE
    `albums_2015`.`eventid` = 1
    AND `album` LIKE '%string%'
    AND `obstacle_time` >= '08:00:00'
    AND `obstacle_time` <= '14:11:10'
    AND `gender` = 1
    AND `top_style` REGEXP '[[:<:]]0[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
    AND `cap` = '2'
    AND `tshirt` = '1'
    AND `pants` = '3'
ORDER BY `obstacle_time`
LIMIT X, 10
```

OR using an `IN` CLAUSE inside `WHERE` like:

```
SELECT `albums`.`filename`,`basket`.`id`,`albums`.`id`,`obstacle_time` 
FROM `albums` 
LEFT JOIN `basket` 
    ON `basket`.`eventid` = `albums`.`eventid` 
        AND `basket`.`fileid` = `albums`.`id` 
        AND `basket`.`visitor_id` = 1 
WHERE 
    `albums_2015`.`eventid` = 1 
    AND `album` LIKE '%string%' 
    AND `obstacle_time` >= '08:00:00' 
    AND `obstacle_time` <= '14:11:10' 
    AND `filename` IN (
        SELECT `filename` 
        FROM `keywrods` 
        WHERE
            `eventid` = 1 
            AND `gender` = 1 
            AND `top_style` REGEXP '[[:<:]]0[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]' 
            AND `cap` = '2' 
            AND `tshirt` = '1' 
            AND `pants` = '3'
    )
ORDER BY `obstacle_time`
LIMIT X, 10
```

I had looked to similar questions but wasn't able to figure it out which is the best course of action.

My understanding so far is that:

- Using `LEFT JOIN`takes advantages of INDEXING, BUT!!! if I use it I will get a full join of the tables even when I only need a significantly smaller result set, so it's almost a wast to join thousands of rows just to then filter out most of them.
- Using IN and subquery isn't indexed??? I'm not 100% sure about this, I'm using MySQL 5.6 and to the best of my understanding since 5.6 even subqueries get automatically indexed my MySQL. I think this method has benefits when there result is significantly filtered, not sure if there will be any benefit if the subquery will return all the possible filenames.

As footnote questions:

- Should I consider returning the whole result to the client on the first query and use client side (HTML) techniques to load the images gradually rather than re-querying the server each time?
- Should I consider merging the 2 tables into 1, how much of a performance impact will that have? (can be tricky due to various reasons, which have no place in the question)

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Explain for JOIN query:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |     table     |  type  | possible_keys |     key      | key_len |                  ref                   | rows |                       Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | albums_2015   | ref    | unique_index  | unique_index | 4       | const                                  | 6475 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | basket        | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                   |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | keywords_2015 | eq_ref | unique_index  | unique_index | 206     | const,mybibnumber.albums_2015.filename |    1 | Using index                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Using WHERE IN:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type |     table     |  type  | possible_keys |     key      | key_len |                  ref                   | rows |                       Extra                        |  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | albums_2015   | ref    | unique_index  | unique_index | 4       | const                                  | 6475 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | keywords_2015 | eq_ref | unique_index  | unique_index | 206     | const,mybibnumber.albums_2015.filename |    1 | Using where                                        |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | basket        | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                                   |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```

**EDIT 2**

I wasn't able to set up a SQL Fiddler (keep getting error of something went wrong), so I have created a test database on one of my servers.

Address: http://188.165.217.185/phpmyadmin/, user: *temp_test*, pass: *test_temp*

I'm still building the whole thing and I don't have all the values filled in yet, like top_style, pants_style, etc, so a more appropriate query for the test scenario will be:

WHERE IN:

```
SELECT `albums_2015`.`filename`, 
       `albums_2015`.`id`, 
       `obstacle_time` 
FROM   `albums_2015` 
WHERE  `albums_2015`.`eventid` = 1 
       AND `album` LIKE '%' 
       AND `obstacle_time` >= '08:00:00' 
       AND `obstacle_time` <= '14:11:10' 
       AND `filename` IN (SELECT `filename` 
                          FROM   `keywords_2015` 
                          WHERE  eventid = 1 
                                 AND 
               `bibnumbers` REGEXP '[[:<:]]113[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]106[[:>:]]') 
ORDER  BY `obstacle_time` 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT `albums_2015`.`filename`,`albums_2015`.`id`,`obstacle_time`
    FROM `albums_2015`
        LEFT JOIN `keywords_2015`
        ON `keywords_2015`.`eventid` = `albums_2015`.`eventid`
            AND `albums_2015`.`filename` = `keywords_2015`.`filename`
    WHERE
        `albums_2015`.`eventid` = 1
        AND `album` LIKE '%'
        AND `obstacle_time` >= '08:00:00'
        AND `obstacle_time` <= '14:11:10'

        AND `bibnumbers` REGEXP '[[:<:]]113[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]106[[:>:]]'

    ORDER BY `obstacle_time`
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What's the result of running those queries with the EXPLAIN prefix?

Comment: Added the explain, you can ignore the name difference between albums and albums_2015 it's the same I just made it prettier for the question.

Answer (score 2):

More a bunch of tips :

- Join using index are the best if you have to deal with multi table query,

Don't mind adding some index to speed up your query (index take space, but on `INT` field it's nothing and you gain way more than you lose).

---

- In case of big table, caching the data in the distant table is usually a good idea.

An insert Trigger on `TAG_table` that cache the displayed part in the distant table (like the tag name for the overview of albums) can help you keeping your join query at a descent frequency.

---

- Be careful with `REGEX`, it's something that **hurt badly the perf**. Adding a new table to split data is a better idea (and use indexing which is native optimisation)

---

- For every field in a `WHERE` clause of a big and frequent query you should have an index on it. If you can't put one, then your DB model is f**cked-up and need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks, just quickly: 1) I already have an index - ADD UNIQUE  `unique_index` (  `eventid` ,  `filename` ) - on both album and keywords table. 2) I will defo consider caching. 3) This is the messy bit, because the column numbers are variable (ex, first row has 3 different values in the bibnumbers field, next row 0, next row 8, etc) hence stuck with the REGEXP approach. 4) Thanks

Comment: @EmilBorconi could you add some data of the tables ? like 5 to 10 lines (it seem I misunderstood how you use it)

Comment: Ok I have created a test enviorment

Comment: @EmilBorconi ok, I really don't like your DB scheme... and the regex on `bibnumbers` is definitely not a good idea as you don't even have an index on it... You should take a look at how to make a DB / split your data between table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377375/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-database-design

Comment: I'm opened to suggestions, but please keep in mind that the keywords table will be populated from a CSV which I receive. Like mentioned before the columns: `bibnumbers`, `gender`, `top_style`, `pants_style`, `other`, `cap`, `tshirt`, `pants` can all have a variable number of values. Let's assume I set a maximum for each of this, so bibnumbers max 20, gender max 2, etc, and instead of keeping them in 1 table and split them in 8 tables, when I run a query I will need to join 8 tables, each of them with 20 OR condition.... are you suggesting that is a better approach?

Comment: @EmilBorconi A DB can take up to 1M lines without any problem (I run a 7M one by example). So for me you should not fear spiting your data to get a "logical" storage, using your `id` field to to make join. This is a *relational db* not a CSV file. you should avoid duplicate data (apart for the cached part) and exploit the join and index with grouping SQL function. You should make a model of the relation of you data, to get the good way to store them (this can depend of the query you'll have to run against it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103626/discussion-between-emil-borconi-and-blag).